# How to make special date disable in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I use the following code to show date input on the checkout page, after additional information:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field' );
function custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Date picker:') . '</h2>';
    woocommerce_form_field(
        'custom_field_name', array(
            'type'        => 'date',
            'class'       => array( 'my-field-class form-row-wide' ),
            'label'       => __( 'Custom Additional Field' ),
            'placeholder' => __( 'New Custom Field' ),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value( 'custom_field_name' )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
```

But there is a problem with this code, all days are selectable, I am looking for a way to make previous days, and Sundays unclickable. Please give me some tips to solve this problem.